# cordova-plugin-geolocation causes 1k of device unsupported

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, cordova-plugins

Today I do testing to find out why there is a lot of devices unsupported on Google Play Store for my app. After some finding, I found out that as soon as I add `cordova-plugin-geolocation` plugin into my app, the supported device drop for 1K.

The `cordova-plugin-geolocation` plugin is important for my app. Why there is so many unsupported device after adding this plugin? How can I reduce the number of unsupported device cause by this plugin? Any other alternative plugin for geolocation detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that Cordova has a permission, which in turn requires a feature, that is not supported on the 1k devices.
If you can figure out which feature, then you can set the feature as optional using the uses-feature optional directive.
For example, for allowing on non phones you use `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>`
Remember, once you set it as optional, it is your responsibility to check for feature before using it, otherwise app will crash.